# Wordpress - Show no posts if category does not match

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have successfully done the hard part with the code below, which is to only show the custom post type content of posts that are of the same category as that of the custom post type being viewed.

The problem I can't solve is that when a new custom post is created and has no category yet, it just shows the latest posts that have been published. How do I get the space to just remain blank, or at worst, render a message like "no posts". Here is my code.

```
<?php

  $cats = get_the_category();
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wall_pledge',
    'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat'     => $cats[0]->term_id
    );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );                         

  if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 

    <!-- Titles of posts of same category -->

  <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of elements in $cats with empty().

```
<?php

  $cats = get_the_category();
  if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wall_pledge',
    'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat'     => $cats[0]->term_id
    );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );                         

  if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 

    <!-- Titles of posts of same category -->

  <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); 
 }
?>
```

Comment: That appears to work as needed. Thanks Zolton!